# Meteor and Mongo in Windows 8

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I started Meteor tutorial and I was able to run a few basic items said in the first 2 steps in the 3 step they ask to add this code

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
```

but when I try to run meteor in the app folder I got (tried it by running Meteor alone and Meteor + Meteor mongo in separate shell of same folder)

```
ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
```

What am I missing here how to make the connection working ?

Answer (score 0):

haha my mistake I think the tutorial given

https://www.meteor.com/try/3

is old or something the issue is sorted when you use

```
Tasks = new Meteor.Collecion
```

instead of 
    new Mongo.Collection

Comment: No, `Mongo.Collection` is the new way and `Meteor.Collection` is the old way. However, Meteor does not yet have official Windows support ([they're working on it now](https://trello.com/c/ZMvnfMfI/11-official-windows-support)), so any native Windows version you're using is probably an old version. For now, so you can develop with the latest version without compatibility issues, I would recommend using something like nitrous.io (very easy to set up) or setting up a VM with vagrant provisioning (a little bit harder, but better - see the Virtualized Solutions section on http://win.meteor.com)